# mixture of experts using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to define a loss function for a mixture of experts neural net. 
I am working with python and tensorflow.

Due to the complexity of the code, it is not possible to copy it all for a working copy (I apologize).

what i have so far is

```
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.matmul(tf.nn.softmax(logits = pred_class),label - experts)))
```

my main problem is: `labels - experts` 
I have 4 experts which return a tensor each (total of 4 tensors). However labels is only one tensor. so I know what im doing here is wrong but I dont know how to fix it. 
(I was also not sure if to use `matmul` or `multiply` in this case.

so the question is how to define this loss function correctly

Comment: Thanks for the comment! (It is helpful). However, it is not a duplicate since I am asking about the formulation given by another paper "Adaptive Mixtures of Local Experts". Nevertheless, this new paper might be just what i needed.

Comment: Alright :) sorry! Maybe read that question/answer and comment here if it doesnt help you. The answer seemed pretty good